# How can I set the cors in fastify server

Tags: reactjs, cors, fastify

I am using Fastify to build a backend API which I want to integrate with a React front end. I have tried registering Cors and its options using a variety of solutions available but nothing seems to work. I have even tried the Fastify Cors approach to no avail. How can I do this in order to work with Apollo client in React because when I make requests to the server using the apollo client I get the error test:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[image: My server code:]

Comment: The server is OK - the error suggests to check the `fetch` options

Comment: Please write the code in text, not image.